# wcf jsonp returning complex type

Tags: c#, wcf, jsonp

I need my wcf app to return a complex type

==============================

case 1 is simply 2 fields. no need to waste anyones time w/ that

==============================
//case 2   - 1 dim array

if the return type looks like this

```
  public class TestResult
    {
        public string Key = "myKey";
        public string Message = "myMessage";
        public string[] fields;
     }
```

and the implementation (snippet) looks like this

```
 r.fields = new string[] { "name", "varchar(32)", "bob" };
 return r;
```

I get what I expect

```
{"GetStringArrayResult":{"Key":"myKey",
                         "Message":"myMessage",
            "fields":["name","varchar(32)","bob"]}}
```

==============================

//case 3  -  2 dim array
if the return class looks like this

```
   public class TestResult
    {
        public string Key = "myKey";
        public string Message = "myMessage";
        public string[][] fields;
    }
```

and the implementation looks like this

```
 string[] a1 =  { "fname", "varchar(32)", "bob"};
            string[] a2 = { "lname", "varchar(50)", "smithersonsonson" };
            string[] a3 = { "age", "varchar(32)", "40" };

            r.fields = new string [][]{a1,a2,a3};
            return r;
```

then i get what i expect in the browser

```
{"GetStringArrayResult":{"Key":"myKey",
                         "Message":"myMessage",
                          "fields":[
                    ["fname","varchar(32)","bob"],
                    ["lname","varchar(50)","smithersonsonson"],
                    ["age","varchar(32)","40"]
                ]
            }
}
```

==============================

you will notice that I am not JSONifying anything. I simply return r and it gets 
JSONP'ed up by wcf.

I learned about this the hard way as I tried to JSON it and then WCF double JSON'ed it which really makes the result ugly. user error.fine.

==============================

so the next step is to have the complex object so we dont have all these arrays hanging around.

//case 4 - A single embedded object

so if i define a simple class like this

```
 public class fieldd
    {
        public string fieldName = "";
        public string datatype = "";
        public string value = "";

        public fieldd(string _fn, string _dt, string _v)
        {
            fieldName = _fn;
            datatype = _dt;
            value = _v;
        }
    }
```

and if my result type looks like this

public class TestResult
    {

```
    public string Key = "myKey";
    public string Message = "myMessage";
    public fieldd field ;

}
```

and my implementation looks like this

r.field = new fieldd("name", "varchar(32)", "bob");
   //return r;

google reports
 ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

ie9 reports 
•Internet connectivity has been lost.
•The website is temporarily unavailable.

What I expected was this

```
{"GetStringArrayResult":{"Key":"myKey",
                         "Message":"myMessage",
                          "field":{
                    "fieldName":"name".
                    "datatype":"varchar(32)",
                    "value":"bob"
                }
            }
}
```

================================

I feel I have pretty fairly demonstrated that wcf is having problems building JSON for the embedded object. It does fine w/ arrays.

any thoughts? 
is there some reason a complex object cant be returned?  
can i turn off wcf's jsonp implementation and do my own?

Answer (score 0):

I wish the answer was more complicated...

After trying many things, I tried taking out the constructor. Success.
After trying many more things... objects have to have a constructor with a blank signature. You can have other constructors, just also have a blank one.

Failing to have a constructor w/ a blank signature will cause the jsonp logic to crash. This happens after the cursor has exited your code and is swimming in the WCF code somewhere.

i have returned to this problem many times over the course of a couple months.
an exception w/ a nice message would have helped, but it is the life...

Greg